# Mathematica 14 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: compatibility, ubuntu, version-14

Currently I am running Mathematica 13.3 on a HP Z240 workstation with Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (x64)

I am entitled to upgrade to Mathematica 14 but 18.04 is not anymore on the official list of supported OS versions for Mathematica 14.

When I asked a support question about the possibility to run Mathematica 14 on 18.04 I got the (somewhat foreseeable) answer that it was not tested and one could neither say it would definitely not work nor the opposite.

My additional question, whether it is possible to install Mathematica 14 and start somehow a comprehensive self-test for the system, which might result in a definitive failure or good situation, was ignored and not answered.

As the system requirements page for linux systems says somewhat vaguely that Mathematica 14 may run also on not listed systems fulfilling a certain kernel and glibc version requirement, I just would like to ask here the community:

1. Has someone successfully run Mathematica 14 on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system?
2. Did problems appear?
3. Is there a way to validate an installation by triggering somehow a comprehensive self-test?

Comment: Yes there are issues.  version `GLIBC_2.28' not found.

Comment: Today, upgrading to the latest Ubuntu via homepage needs less than half an hour.